# When I use spring-cloud-stream to send rabbitmq messages, I cannot specify the RoutingKey sent

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I use the 3.1.3 version. After the following configuration,'output-out-0.producer.bindingRoutingKey' does not take effect. When I send a message, Routing keys = command_exchange_open instead of: ORDER_PUSH

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: amqp://sycx:sycx@192.168.1.204
  cloud:
    stream:
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          input-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: ORDER_PUSH
              exchangeType: direct
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
          output-out-0:
            producer:
              bindingRoutingKey: ORDER_PUSH
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
              bindQueue: false
      bindings:
        input-in-0:
          destination: command_exchange_open
          group: ORDER_END
        output-out-0:
          destination: command_exchange_open
          group: ORDER_END
    function:
      definition: input;output
```

Comment: You have `bindQueue: false`. The documentation states the following: "The routing key with which to bind the queue to the exchange (if bindQueue is true). ". Any reason why it is 'false'?

Comment: You have set the wrong producer properties; see my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I should set routing-key-expression instead of: bindingRoutingKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The producer property should be `routing-key-expression: '''ORDER_PUSH'''` not `bindingRoutingKey`.

```
          output-out-0:
            producer:
              bindingRoutingKey: ORDER_PUSH
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
              bindQueue: false
```

These properties do not apply to producers (unless you have `required-groups` set).

Comment: Thank you for your help, as you said. I have solved this problem with your help.